# Deleting file with reserved characters via SSH

Tags: macos, ssh, console

While developing a server-side application, I accidentally created a couple of files that are named similar to this:

```
<?php echo $_GET[\'team\'] ?>files.json
```

Even after I add the necessary backslashes to try to `rm` those files, Terminal says those files don't exist. My FTP GUI will not delete them either.

I'd appreciate help with how to deal with this situation — I couldn't find anything via Google or Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I could have used a more precise pattern, but this is what I did:**

I `ended up` backing up my legitimate JSON files and creating a perl script in a subdirectory that would delete all the JSON files in that directory:

```
$filepath= "../*.json";
@jsonPattern=glob($filepath);
unlink @jsonPattern;
```

Then I ran that by cd-ing into that subdir and entering `perl nameOfMyScript.perl`

Comment: You can select your own answer as the correct one, it is the correct way to do it [Meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions)

Answer (score 0):

One common approach is to use something like Perl or Ruby to delete the file:

```
perl -e 'unlink("random crazy file")'
ruby -e 'File.unlink("random crazy file")'
```

That avoids the whole shell thing.

The other easy way to do it, with an interactive shell like bash, is to type `rm fi`, hit tab, and let bash complete the filename for you.  That quotes well.

Comment: Unfortunately none of those solutions work on that filename. Even rm's autocomplete fails on its own suggestion. The perl & ruby options work on regular filenames but go into some new command line mode on the file I want to remove.

Comment: One other options, if you have GNU rm, is `rm -i *` and answer yes/no to the "delete this file" question...

Comment: — thanks for the help. Your answer did lead me to use perl even though that's not what I'd wanted to use.